# Is it possible to mock a list of files?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, jfilechooser

I'm trying to mock a `JFileChooser` where a number of files have been selected.  At the moment I have a single file mocked.

In the for loop the `selctedFiles` variable hasn't been initialised.  I'd like to loop several files.  Am I heading in the right direction?

```
@Test
public void testValidateFile()
{
    String name = this.getName();
    System.out.println("Test case Name = " + name);

    JFileChooser fileChooser = mock(JFileChooser.class);
    when(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(masterView.getContentPane())).thenReturn(0);
    when(fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()).thenReturn(new File("/myImages/IMG_0037.JPG"));

    for (File currentFile : selectedFiles) {
        System.out.println(currentFile.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, [`JFileChooser.getSelectedFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles%28%29) returns a `File` array (not a list of `File`s). Even if it were a list, you wouldn't need to mock the list itself. You'd just use a normal list with `File` objects and mock the `JFileChooser` to return that list. In this case you use a `File` array, though.

First create the `File` array:

```
File[] files = { new File("f1"), new File("f2"), new File("f3") };
```

Then mock the `JFileChooser` object:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = mock(JFileChooser.class);
when(fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()).thenReturn(files);
```

You could then loop through the array returned by `fileChooser` like this:

```
for (File currentFile : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
    //...
}
```